# pointer reference type

Tags: c++, reference, types

I am trying to write a function that takes a pointer argument, modifies what the pointer points to, and then returns the destination of the pointer as a reference.
I am getting the following error: `cannot convert int*** to int* in return`

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int* increment(int** i) {
    i++; 
    return &i;
}

int main() {
    int a=24;
    int *p=&a;
    int *p2;
    p2=increment(&p);
    cout<<p2;
}
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Please format your code more clearly. It's far easier for us to read and thus help you; and it helps make your error-finding much easier (the line numbers for error messages will help you more).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you indeed mean "return the destination of the pointer as a reference", then I think the return type you're after is `int&` rather than `int*`.

This can be one of the confusing things about C++, since `&` and `*` have different meanings depending on where you use them. `&` is "Reference type" if you're talking about a variable definition or return type; but it means "Address of" if it's in front of a variable being used after it's defined.

I could be completely mistaken, but it seems to me that you've gotten these two meanings mixed up; and since you want to return a reference, you've written "`return &i`", since `&` is used for references. However, in this case, it returns the *address* of `i`. And since `i` is a pointer to a pointer to an int, in this line of code:

```
int* increment(int** i) { i++; return &i;}
```

you are returning the address of a pointer to a pointer to an `int`. That is why you are getting your error message `cannot convert int***' to int*`.

Let's walk through your code line by line. You are after a program that takes a **pointer** and returns a reference. So that would be:

```
int& increment(int* i)
```

We don't need the double pointer that you had in your code (unless you want a pointer to a pointer). Then you want it to modify what the pointer points to:

```
(*i)++;
```

And then return the destination of the pointer as a reference:

```
return *i;
```

Here, we are dereferencing `i`. Remember that using references lets you treat them like normal variables, and handles the pointer stuff for you. So C++ will figure out that you want it to be a reference.

Then, to use your code, you can do pretty much what you had, but using less pointers:

```
int a=24;
int *p=&a;
int *p2;
p2 = increment(p);
```

I haven't tested any of this, so anyone may feel free to edit my answer and fix it if I've got something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

```
int* increment(int** i) { (**i)++; return *i;}
```

and

```
cout << *p2;
```

Comment: `&i` returns `int ***` whereas function defines return type as `int *`. You need to dereference `i`.

Comment: @Code: reference to what? `*i` is also a reference to `**i`. Try to run the code with suggested changes and see if that is what you want.